# Get model index from MapItemView

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to build an interactive map application which allow me to add and modify Map Items. I am able to add new map item but I still have problem to modify the model. On the code below, if I have more than one item, the `remove` function always delete the first item crated not the current item selected. I want to modify the model not only the view of the model, but how can I get the `currentIndex` of the model ?

```
ListModel {
    id: mapModel
}

Map {
    id: map
    //...
    MapItemView {
        model: mapModel
        delegate: MapCircle {
            radius: 80000
            color: 'blue'
            center {
                latitude: lat
                longitude: longi
            }
            MouseArea {
                onClicked: {
                    mapModel.remove(model.index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var coord = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
            mapModel.append({lat : coord.latitude, longi: coord.longitude});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Just use `mapModel.remove(index)` instead of `mapModel.remove(model.index)`